# Rmarkdown to Word output - insert page number for word document

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am editing a Rmarkdown file, I want to know is there a solution to insert page numbers for word in rmd file which will output to a word document.

```
---
title: "title"
output:
word_document:
    reference_docx: ../template/template.docx
```

---

Comment: Hello @Minyi Han. Did you manage to number pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In MS Word, edit the header or footer of your word template file (`../template/template.docx`) to include a Word placeholder for the page number.  Not only will that provide page numbers, but they will update if the document is edited or reformatted.

Comment: There is an explanation for how to create and use a word template file at https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html.

Comment: Hello DonJ. How do you put a placeholder in word?

Comment: @itamar, in Word 2007 it's ribbon "Insert", button "Page Number".

Comment: Thanks @A.Donda